# GraphicRaycaster on the child object containing buttons blocks Raycast from the parent object containing GraphicRaycaster. How to solve it?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

What I'm trying to achieve is to detect clicks on buttons in UI. Here is the tree:
I have a parent object SlotMachineScreen containing GraphicRaycaster with a script detecting clicks attached to it:

```
if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            //Set up the new Pointer Event
            m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(null);
            //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
            m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

            //Create a list of Raycast Results
            List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

            //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
            m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);
            foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Hit " + result.gameObject.name);
            }
        }
```

And there are a bunch of child objects with a GraphicRaycaster (red ones) with buttons in it, that I want to detect a click on. But there is no response from my sprit at all when I click on them.

I found one solution so far, but its not what I need: the solution is to move all buttons from child containers to SlotMachineScreen.
Are there any different ways to solve this problem?

[image: Tree]

[image]

Comment: You generally don't need a graphic raycaster on every object that catches rays. The raycaster handles *firing* the rays, so you can have just one in your whole scene. What matters for catching / blocking rays is how you've configured your button or image or other UI components. Can you show us that?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, updated the question